# difference between jealousy and envy

Tags: vocabulary

I don't have a car. My friend has one. I don't want him to lose his car but I want that I also get a car i.e. I don't have any ill feeling for him. I just want what he has I can also get one like that.

I am envious of him.

Right?

Answer (score 1):

In your context *envious* and *jealous* are synonyms. But generally, *jealous* includes a meaning that *envious* does not possess:

> upset and angry because someone that you love seems interested in another person:
>
> - a jealous husband/wife ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jealous))

Here you can't say *an envious husband and wife* with that meaning.